# SharePoint Online Remote authentication using JSOM script

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, authentication

Could anyone share script to authenticate SharePoint Online using jQuery/ajax method. I can see some forum, using POSTMAN tool to authenticate. But I want to do through 
script not using any tool. Site url is like below

`https://spteamspace.sharepoint.com/sites/myteamapp/`and my SPO username is like `xyz.abc@companyname.com`

Appreciate your help..!

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something similar to what you are asking for. In the meantime, maybe, the following library could help you do this stuff, [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js). Take a look and see if this can fit your needs.